# Why do I get a "Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES" error in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I created a TableView with a TableViewCell and always have the View opening. I have this error:

> Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES

I'm using XIB file to design my TableViewCell and the TableView.

This is my TableView:

```
public partial class FavoriteProjectsView : MvxTableViewController<FavoriteProjectsViewModel>
{
    public FavoriteProjectsView() : base("FavoriteProjectsView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // ios7 layout
        if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
        {
            EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        }

        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(TableView, FavoriteProjectsItem.Key, FavoriteProjectsItem.Key);
        TableView.Source = source;

        this.CreateBinding(source).To<FavoriteProjectsViewModel>(viewModel => viewModel.Projetos).Apply();
        this.CreateBinding(BtnSave).To<FavoriteProjectsViewModel>(viewModel => viewModel.SaveCommand).Apply();

        var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        var carregamento = new CarregamentoIOS(bounds);

        ViewModel.Carregamento = carregamento;
        ViewModel.PreenchePagina();
    }
}
```

This is my TableViewCell:

```
public partial class FavoriteProjectsItem : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("FavoriteProjectsItem");
    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("FavoriteProjectsItem", NSBundle.MainBundle);

    protected FavoriteProjectsItem(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            this.CreateBinding(LblName).To<Project>(project => project.Name).Apply();
            this.CreateBinding(SwitchFavorite).To<Project>(project => project.IsFavorite).Apply();
        });
    }

    public static FavoriteProjectsItem Create()
    {
        return (FavoriteProjectsItem)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using MvvmCross or some other Mvvm library?

It's only a guess at this point but it would seem that something, somewhere is setting a property `_setHostsLayoutEngine:YES` but that this setting requires Auto Layout constraints, which may have been disabled with a call on the view to `view.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

The old system of laying out views in iOS was to use something called `AutoResizing`. The `AutoResizing` flags can either be set in code or in the XIB/Storyboard. If you are using `AutoLayout`, the new and improved layout system that uses constraints and offers much more flexibility (and complexity), for the XIB/Storyboard then any `AutoResizing` flags should be converted automatically into constraints that can be used with the `AutoLayout` system. This is the default behavior, but can be disabled with the call noted above, `view.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

For more information about using AutoLayout with Xamarin iOS Designer, please see: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/

Comment: Thanks man, that's workerd. Answering your question, yes, I'm using MvvmCross.

Comment: Great, glad that helped!